# Implications of a model structure in which every object is fibrant and cofibrant?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory

If we are trying to study a category using model categories, is it a "good" or "bad" thing if our choices of fibrations and cofibrations make everything fibrant and cofibrant? Does it signal that our choices were somehow naive?

Comment: The objects are all cofibrant and fibrant. I edited the title to make this more clear.

Comment: Having every object fibrant and cofibrant is optimal.  It is ideally what you want, but it is rare in nature.

Comment: If all objects are fibrant-cofibrant then the homotopy category is just the quotient by the homotopy relation on maps, so it's really good. I would disagree with Randall about the rarity however, in a sense : if you take any model category $C$, you have a full model subcategory of fibrant-cofibrant objects which you tend to work in rather than in $C$ (via fibrant-cofibrant replacement). So it doesn't indicate anything on the model structure, perhaps rather on the underlying category (you took CW-complexes instead of spaces)